# Drupal sidebar block is not visible after changing title of some sidebar blocks

Tags: drupal

I am completely new to Drupal. As part of my new job, I am handling a Drupal(8) website too. I changed the title of sidebar_right blocks (structure -> block layout -> sidebar_right -> configure). After that sidebar is not visible in the website. What can I do to solve this problem? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to remove the title again.
2. Do that never again on the live site!
3. Do that only on your local copy of this site.
4. And then debug this systematically.
5. Make regular backups of the database.
6. Make a backup of the database before you start changing something.
7. Restore the most recent database backup if something went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to remove the title and add it again.

Comment: I have changed the title. But still blocks are not visible on the site. Shall I remove the blocks from sidebar and add again?

Comment: I tried to add other blocks in sidebar. But even that blocks are are not showing. The sidebar is not at all visible in the website.